# Android SQLite: should I use beginTransaction and endTransaction only at insert or both insert and read queries?

Tags: android, sqlite

ATM when I write to the SQLite in my android app, I do it this way:

```
try {
    for (User user: users) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        databaseManager.database.beginTransaction();
        values.put("user_name", user.getName());
        values.put("user_email", user.getEmail());
        databaseManager.database.insert("users", null, values);
    }
    databaseManager.database.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    databaseManager.database.endTransaction();
}
```

But when I read from the DB, I dont use begin, setsuccessful and end:

```
Cursor cursor = databaseManager.database.rawQuery(SQLQueries.getUsers(), null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    if (cursor!=null) {
        do {
            User user = new User();
            try {
                user.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("user_name")));
                user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("user_email")));                        
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            users.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}

if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
    cursor.close();
    cursor = null;
}
```

Should I add beginTransaction, setTransactionSuccessful and endTransaction to the read operations as well? Im pretty sure I shouldnt, but I need to be 100% on this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are not using explicit transactions, SQLite will automatically wrap a transaction around every statement.

When you write to the database, every `insert`/`update`/`delete` call is a single statement.
If you are doing multiple such operations, you use transactions to avoid paying the transaction overhead for each of them.

A query (`query` or `rawQuery`) is a single statement, even if it returns multiple rows.
Therefore, using a transaction around a single query does not make *any* difference.
(If you have multiple queries, you could use a transaction to ensure that their results are consistent with each other even if another thread attempts to change the database between them.)

Comment: so If I have multiple reads, I should wrap them all in a begin/set/end transaction?

Comment: That depends on whether you need them to be atomic.

Comment: More, since a query **doesn't modify** the database contents, including it in a transaction would be meaningless. So use transactions for commands, multiple ones: should they succeed or fail **all together**.